# iphone 12 not waking up and no vibration when receiving text

Tags: iphone, messages, sleep-wake, notifications

I have an iphone 12 running 16.5.1. I've noticed this issue for the past couple weeks where my phone, when locked, no longer vibrates or wakes up when I receive a text. My messages app is set to "Allow Notifications" and on Alerts, all 3 is checked for Lock Screen, Notification Center, and Banners.

Can someone help me debug this issue?

I don't have do not disturb on.

Comment: Check all your focus modes.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't have the "Focus" thing on right now

Comment: did you check the physical mute switch on the side?

Comment: @Andra yeah it's on silent. I should also note that it does work, but only sometimes, probably works less often than it doesn't work. maybe there's a hardware issue?

Comment: I know you said you don't have a focus mode on, but are you sure it's not the sleep focus mode that turns on automatically a little before your bedtime? You can check your bedtime focus mode in the `Health` app > `Sleep`.